# MySQL REGEXP búsqueda como un "like" dentro de un parámetro definido

Tags: mysql, regex

Yo he llegado hasta el siguiente query pero todavía no quedó como espero

```
SELECT
fieldA,
fieldB,
fieldC
from tableName
where
fieldC REGEXP(CONCAT('(AA\\(+', 'findStr', '){1}(\\)\\-){1}'))
```

Algunos registros de ejemplo de fieldC. Notar que AA( y su cierre )- puede estar en cualquier parte de la cadena

```
AA(DALMINE)-AI(SEAMLESS CARBON STEE)-
AA(PESCANOVA/RIAZOR)-AI(L4= 40/59 PZ/KG)-AJ(6 CAJAS X 2 KGN)-CA00-SA01-NA04-NB01-
AA(ARBUMASA)-AI(L3= 31/40 PZA/KG)-AJ(6 CAJAS X 2 KGN)-CA00-SA01-NA03-NB01-
AA(BUCYRUS)-AB(62029517)-CA00-
ZA(000170)-ZB(000230)-AA(PESANTAR/ECZ)-AI(MZA COLA FILET MS)-AJ(3 ESTUCHES X 6,8 KG)-CA00-PA00-PB00-PC01-PD01-
ZA(300000)-ZB(400000)-AA(ARGE/ NOVA/ RIAZOR)-AI(4= 3000/4000 GR/PZ)-AJ(ENVUELTA INDIVIDUAL)-CA00-PA04-PB00-PC00-PD02-PE00-SA01-
AA(PESPASA)-AI(CR = COLA ROTO)-AJ(6 CAJAS X 2 KGN)-CA00-SA01-NA01-NB00-NC01-
```

Un ejemplo para que se entienda mejor

```
ZA(000070)-AA(CONIGLIO)-AI(WU PEPE/B)-CA00-PA00-NA00-
```

Necesito buscar la cadena pepe, tiene que comenzar en este caso con 'AI(' y terminar con ')-', si utilizo la expresión

```
AI\(.+PEPE.+\)\-{1}
```

o

```
AA\(.+PEPE.+\)\-{1}
```

en ambos casos lo encuentra ya que es válido, debería poder contabilizar las aperturas de los paréntesis para que sea 1 y así únicamente funcionaría en el primer caso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si no te he entendido mal quieres realizar una búsqueda que te devuelva los registros que contienes un texto determinado entre los paréntesis que siguen al literal "AA".

Entonces deberías utilizar:

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE fieldC REGEXP 'AA\\([^\\)]*NOVA[^\\)]*\\)-';
```

o

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE fieldC REGEXP 'AI\\([^\\)]*COLA[^\\)]*\\)-';
```

La primera consulta busca aquellos registros que contengan el literal NOVA dentro de los paréntesis AA(....)-, mientras que la segunda consulta busca los que contienen el literal COLA dentro de los paréntesis AI(....)-

Puedes ver el ejemplo funcionando en este [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/35eac/14)

Si lo que quieres es buscar una palabra completa tendrías que definir qué condiciones definen que es una palabra. Por ejemplo podrías definir que se considera palabra si el carácter anterior es la apertura de paréntesis o un espacio y el carácter posterior es el cierre de paréntesis o un espacio:

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE fieldC REGEXP 'AI\\(([^\\)]*[[:blank:]])?COLA([[:blank:]][^\\)]*)?\\)-';
```

Esta consulta te devolverá resultados que contengan por ejemplo:

AI(COLA EERE3)-  AI(EEEE COLA XXXX)- AI(EIEIE332 COLA)-  AI(COCA COLA ERRRR)-

Pero no te devolverá un resultado como:
AI(COCA-COLA ERRRR)-

Comment: Esto es exactamente lo que necesitaba!... gracias

Comment: Para perfeccionar la aplicación me quedaría resolver lo siguiente. Con esta expresión se busca dentro de AA (...)- la cadena COLA. Si yo quisiera por ejemplo diferenciar COCA-COLA de COCA COLA, cual sería la variante. La expuesta por usted siempre encuentra ambas COLA

Comment: Edito la respuesta para tener en cuenta este caso

Comment: IMPECABLE!, realmente encontré un experto en expresiones regulares.  Muchas Gracias, me has ahorrado horas de investigación